How to spy on nested method in service constructor in angular unit test
I have an Angular service which depends on another service, which has a property, which is an object contains a method I want to spy on.
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
    constructor(
        private secondService:SecondService,
    ) {
        this.secondService.someObj.someMethod();
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SecondService {
    someObj = {
        someMethod: () => {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}

How to spy on someMethod when testing MyService?

You can create a createSpyObj for that secondary service, where the first parameter is the service mock name, second is the methods and third is the properties.
describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let mockValidator: jasmine.SpyObj<SecondService>;
  const someObj = {
                someMethod: () => {
                      //do stuff
                }
          } as any;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn<any>(someObj, 'someMethod');
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        DataService,
        { provide: ValidationService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('SecondService', [], 
          {'someObj': someObj  }) 
        }
      ]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
    secondService = TestBed.get(SecondService);
  });

  it('someMethod should be called on constructor', () => {
    expect(someObj.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

